# What is the recommended way to make a PUT request to an external API in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple app that retrieves a record from an external API and displays the value ("day"). The day value can be incremented by passing it into a component with a simple action. My app is retrieving the record correctly and is successfully passing it to the component. But once it has incremented the value I can't figure out the best way to `save` the record back to the external API.

My `route` fetches the object like this:

```
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('world', '5cb0f8bd3b74cf22b75e1a37', { reload: true });
  },
})
```

This is my `model`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { attr } = DS;

export default Model.extend({
  day: attr('Number'),
});
```

In my template the day value is mapped to my component with:

```
<Wait @day={{model.day}}></Wait>
```

And my component has a button that calls the action like this:

```
<button {{action "incrementDay"}} class="btn btn-default" aria-hidden="true">Wait</button>
```

Finally, here is my `component`:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  router: service(),
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    incrementDay() {
      this.day++;
      console.log(this.day);
    }
  }
});
```

Each time I press the button the console outputs the incremented number successfully, but I'm not sure how to then save the changes back to the API. What is the best way to make a PUT request back to the API with the changed data?

Comment: use `save` method on model? https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.8/classes/DS.Model/methods/save?anchor=save

Comment: From inside the component? Where do I specify which record to update with this.day?

Comment: You have model instance on the controller, if you want to save your changes in the model, you have to run `save` method on the whole model. For example(actually bad example, but just to show the variant.. ):

// send whole model into component
<Wait @day={{model}}></Wait>

// get the day property from model in action and increment it and then just run:
this.model.save()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to pass the whole model to your component. like this:

```
<Wait @someBetterName={{@model}} />
```

(as an aside, you may want to have your model be a hash of things so you can use more canonical names for things)

```
async model() {
  let myModelA = await this.store...
  // ...
  return {
    modelA: myModelA,
    modelB: myModelB,

  }
}
```

but then inside Wait, you could have your action do this:

```
  actions:{
    async incrementDay() {
      let day = this.someBetterName.day;
      this.someBetterName.set('day', day + 1);

      await this.someBetterName.save();
      console.log('saved!')
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you think, is it good to use `incrementProperty` method for this case?

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best approach, but what's tripping me up is that I haven't defined a setter anywhere.  When I apply your solution I get the expected error `TypeError: setting getter-only property "day"` My impulse would be to use a controller, but I've been told that in Ember you should always use components instead and I'm not sure what that would look like.

Comment: a controller wouldn't really solve the problem, but move it. you could also use incrementProperty.

but the getter-only property thing seems like a misleading error to me.  What happens if you do `set(this.someBetterName, 'day', day + 1)` where set is `import { set } from '@ember/object';`? (I'm also curious what happens if you use increment property as well. It's just that ember-data attributes shouldn't be read-only. :-\\

Comment: I'm not sure why ember-data attributes was read-only, but importing { set } fixed it. I'm going to play around and see if I can figure out what caused ember-data to not be able to write.